# Change Password on Domain Account from CMD Line

Tags: command-line-interface, active-directory, windows-server-2008

Quick background. My organization recently changed from Lotus Notes to Microsoft Outlook. I have some production users that were formerly using Lotus Webmail that will be using Outlook WebApp. With Notes it used the users internet credentials to authenticate. That password never expired, it was easy to show these people how to check it.

The machines they are using have generic windows logins. Outlook uses AD credentials to authenticate and that password must be changed every 45 days. These users do not use AD account, so they will not be prompted. So every 45 days that means I will have to call help desk have their password reset and then find a computer somewhere and login as them one time, just to change their password. I have rights to add them to groups, but not to change their password.

Is there a systematic way (script) that I could automate this, put in in a scheduled task that every 40 days it will increment their password by 1? Example this time there password is Jdoe1 and next time it is Jdoe2, etc. I have tried a few of the CMD line examples to change password, but it seems you have to be domain admin to run them.

```
dsquery user -samid DoeJ | dsmod user -pwd Pa$$word1!
net user DoeJ Pa$$word1! /domain
```

These are the two variations that I have seen. I have tried a few different ways to get it to work but no dice. I have the users own username/password and I'd like to change it without having to go to a desktop to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why on earth would you do this? Why not just have the users log in as themselves, or have them change their own passwords? To do what you want to do, you'd have to know everyone's password, which is bad bad bad.

Comment: The users I deal with. Having them go to a random client and login once ever 45 days, just to change password, I know I would just end up getting a call every 45 days to change their password. The dkwiebe solution below will work well though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not setup OWA to allow password changes?

Here's the relevant information from Microsoft.

[Exchange Server 2010 SP2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684904.aspx)

[Exchange Server 2007 and older](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297121)